# File size validation error not store in array

Tags: php, validation

I don't understand why file size validation error doesn't show if file size excess 500kb and if excess file size limit, it stores file name and file url in the database but file not store to the destination.

```
if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
    $pic=$_FILES['pic']['name'];

    $allow_extension= array("png", "jpg", "jpeg");
    $extension=pathinfo($_FILES['pic']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $errors=array();

    if(!in_array($extension,$allow_extension)) {
        $errors[]='Invalid file format. Try JPG, JPEG, PNG';
    }
    if ($_FILES['pic']['size']>500000) {
        $errors[]='Image size is more than 500kb';
    }

    if (empty($errors)==true) {
            $pic=time().$pic;
            $target="../images/slider/". $pic;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'],$target);
            $store="INSERT INTO slider (slider_name,slider_url) VALUES ('$pic', '$target')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn,$store)) {
                $msg="Store slider successful.";
                header("location:slider.php?msg=$msg");
            }
    }
        else {
            $msg=implode('. ', $errors);
            header("location:slider.php?msg=$msg");
        }
    }
```

Comment: $msg needs to be urlencoded. It is `Location: slider.php` (capital and space after colon). You are vulnerable to SQL injections. No need to check for true on `empty($errors)`. Either it is or not.

Comment: For starters, make a debug output of $_FILES['pic'], and see what the `size` entry actually contains.

Comment: @04FS If I remove ['size'] inside the condition then it works fine. Thanks. But let me know, it's not allowed to use at present version?

Comment: _“If I remove ['size'] inside the condition then it works fine.”_ - that doesn’t actually make sense. Show the output of `var_dump($_FILES);`, please.

Comment: @04FS http://prntscr.com/qr6npx

Comment: @04FS sorry It shows error message if it is less than 500kb too.

Comment: Well 0 is not really greater than 500000, now is it? You have a `1` under the `error` key here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php Your upload was rejected by PHP, before your script was even started - due to the upload size limits in the PHP configuration.

Comment: @04FS if I use  " if ($_FILES['file']['size'] > 1000000 || $_FILES['file']['size'] === 0) " then it show exact message. By the way, thank you for your cooperation.